# Add Laravel Support in Aptana

Tags: php, laravel, aptana3

I wish to add auto-complete with documentation for `Laravel in Aptana 3.0`

Tough I managed to create auto-complete (just by mapping a few methods in it)

https://github.com/danielboendergaard/laravel-helpers/blob/9798026ede3722d6a9570684e987f7ed81b41013/ide_helper.php

This doesn't seem to be quite effective, how to we add method documentation for it too?

Comment: I too would like to know how to do this...

Comment: What about method documentation does not work? That file should enable that.

Comment: It does to an extent Franz, I did some digging into this yesterday. Aptana recognises the parameters required for a static function call but does not recognise the method names. I think its more to do with how Laravel instantiates the static methods, than lack of documentation.

Comment: @DavidBarker is this still an issue? Looking at the current [ide_helper.php](https://github.com/danielboendergaard/laravel-helpers/blob/master/ide_helper.php) you've made some great progress on this. I only ask because this is quite a highly voted for, unanswered question.

Comment: @DavidBarker - I think you're right. Static calls in Laravel 4 are resolved via the Facade system, and I'm not sure if Aptana would follow this properly. Technically, Aptana is correct, but it's using the wrong class in the case of facade implementation, and I'm not sure how easy that will be to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of helpers currently available on Github for Laravel 4. If this is still an issue with Aptana I would suggest using this package:
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

I use Eclipse, and it really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the generated file [barryvdh / _ide_helper.php](https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822) to your project in Aptana.